# Symbolic link not present in final image file system when using multilib feature in Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, symlink, bitbake, image-file

I am new to Yocto and face an issue in which the final image that I built does not have a symbolic link.

The situation is as follows: I wish to build the `libpam` library for both 64 (this is my target architecture) and 32 bit.
To do so, I enabled the MULTILIB feature as follows:
`MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"`

When I build the image, indeed I see that both `libpam` and `lib32-libpam` packages are built. During the `do_install` of each package,
I see that the symbolic link to the libpam.so.X is created and placed under the "desired" location: For the 64 bit, it is placed under `/lib64/libpam.so` (points to `/lib64/libpam.so.X`)
and for the 32 bit under `/lib/libpam.so` (points to `/lib/libpam.so.X`)

**However**, when examining the final image file system, the `/lib/libpam.so` is NOT present! Other files under `/lib` that are related to the 32 bit flavor `libpam` DO EXIST, for
example, the `/lib/libpam.so.X` IS PRESENT).

I tried to examine all BitBake's different tasks of each on of the `libpam` packages (i.e. - `libpam` & `lib32-libpam`), in particular, I looked at the: `do_compile`, `do_install`, `do_package`, `do_populate_sysroot`,
`do_package_write_rpm` - but did not find any "difference" in their behaviour.

The ONLY difference I found was in the `libpam.spec` Vs. `lib32-libpam.spec` files: In the `libpam.spec` (which is for the 64 bit flavor), there was the
following:

```
//....
%files -n libpam-dev
%defattr(-,-,-,-)
%dir "/lib64"
%dir "/usr"
"/lib64/libpam.so"
"/lib64/libpam_misc.so"
"/lib64/libpamc.so"
//....
```

NOTE the `"/lib64/libpam.so"` presence.

I also tried to look at logs of the final image recipe (i.e. - `my-core-image.bb`) log files but did not find anything "intersting" about it.

My questions are: Does Yocto/BitBake have some "mechanism" to remove symbolic links with the same name (but that are located under a different folders)?
If so - where can I see it "takes place"? Also - is it possible to disable it?

Otherwise - is there anything else I can do/change so that the 32 bit flavor symbolic link (i.e. - `/lib/libpam.so`) will be included in the final image file system? How do I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your setup? What does your local.conf look like? Which layers are you using? How did you try to include the multilib version in you image?